# How can I set the value of a textbox in Dart?

Tags: dart

I have a textbox field with `id="textbox1"`. How do I set its value?

This is what I tried:

```dart
query('#textbox1').text = 'test 123';
```

But it did not work.

Comment: `query('input#foo').value = 'test';` -- I added `input` word in the query selector only because it helps the IDE to understand the returned value is an instance of `InputElement`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```dart
InputElement input = querySelector("#textbox1");
input.value = "test123";
```

Tips : When you use `querySelector(selector)` you can type the result with what you expect (a [`InputElement`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/InputElement.html) here). Thus, editor will provide content assist to help you.

Comment: The annotation will give you help from the static analyzer and Dart Editor, but it should be noted that the Type may in fact still be incorrect at runtime(if #textbox1 were a DIV for example).  If you want a runtime check, you'll need to use "if (input is InputElement){}" or cast with "var input = query('#textbox1') as InputElement".  Careful with these though, as there is a runtime performance cost.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `query` is now deprecated. For all those that find this through Google as I did, here is updated

```js
InputElement input = querySelector("#textbox1");
input.value = "test123";
```

Comment: @Michael. It was not a copy when I posted it. The original answer was edited to reflect my changes weeks after I posted this answer.

Comment: sorry than. Can't 'unvote' till answer edited somehow :(